# Custom dialog throws WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android

im trying to create custom dialog, but im getting an error when calling show() function. I am not sure if i missed some step in creating the dialog.  here's the code:

```
public class TrackerSettingsActivity extends Activity { 
Context context;
PhoneStateBroadcastReciever prefs;
Handler handler;
SharedPreferences m_sharedPrefs;
Editor editor;

EditText timerDelay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tracker_settings);

    timerDelay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Set_Timer);
    m_sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    editor = m_sharedPrefs.edit();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Confirm);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customDialog().show();

        }
         }
private Dialog customDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}


}
```

login_dialog.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/image"
     android:text="sss"
     android:textColor="#FFF" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
     android:layout_width="100px"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/text"
     android:text=" Ok " />
```

tracker_settings.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Set_Timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:text="@string/tv_settimer"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_Set_Timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_Set_Timer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Set_Timer"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_Confirm"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Set_Timer"
    android:onClick="click"
    android:text="@string/bn_confirm" />
```

I dont know why show() wont work...
If someone have some other suggestion im am willing to listen...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception WindowManager$BadTokenException))

Comment: Dialog.show() line: 286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: use activity reference when you have to create a Dialog.

```
Actvity activity = this;
private Dialog customDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity); // or new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login_dialog);
    ....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your custom dialog can't be added due to it not having a parent view. As @jzafrilla has stated, add an activity reference to your constructor, so that android knows what to attach it to.

```
... = new Dialog(Main.this); // or something similar
```

If you do this, then you should be able to see your dialog on top of the parent view